# Select based on list of pairs

Tags: select, query, netezza

I have a table with two main columns, `id1` and `id2`:

```
drop table if exists pairs;
create table pairs (id1 int, id2 int);
insert into pairs values
    (1,2), (1,3), (3,1), (2,4), (5,4), (3,6), (7,8);
```

I want to select rows which have these pairs `[(1,2),(5,4),(3,1)]`. This array could have more than 500 items, so how I can write a select query to select those rows?
I am using 'Netezza' database but I need to find the logic to do this, I can figure out how to implement this logic in my database engine.

Comment: Does this array of pairs come from another table?

Comment: @danblack No, Actually I want to make a store procedure to get those arrays from user, I don't think that I am gonna to save them into a separate table unless I have to do it

Answer (score 0):

I would start with:

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM pairs
WHERE id1 IN (1,5,3) AND id2 IN (2,4,1)
```

The '1,5,3' and '2,4,1' can also be results from another query.